# How to get scale value when scroll zoom in d3js v7?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

how can i get d3.event.scale in d3 v7?
I have seen this changed to d3.event.transform.scale but no mention how to get this attribute in v7, i got event is undefied even if i pass event in zoomed function.When i console.log data.transform i cant find the scale attribute. Also the transform.k value interval is too big for me (it goes from 1 to 3 to 6 ,10 ) where as i have seen other peoples scale goes up very small interval when they scroll(0.00001), how can i achive this with my code

```
  d3.select(svgRef)
      .call(
        d3
          .zoom()
          .scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
          .on("zoom", zoomed)
          .filter((event) => {
            return event.ctrlKey;
          }),
        d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1),
      )

...
 const zoomed = (data: any) => {
    const transform = data.transform || d3.zoomIdentity;
    // Translate x, y coordinates if zooming
    if (data.sourceEvent.deltaY) {
      // Calculate the scale change
      const scaleDelta = Math.pow(2, data.sourceEvent.deltaY * 0.001);

      // Get the cursor position in the SVG coordinate system
      const cursorPosition = d3.pointer(data.sourceEvent, svgRef);

      // Calculate the new translate and scale values to zoom around the cursor position
      const newTranslateX =
        transform.x - (cursorPosition[0] - transform.x) * (scaleDelta - 1);
      const newTranslateY =
        transform.y - (cursorPosition[1] - transform.y) * (scaleDelta - 1);

      // Apply the new transform values
      const newTransform: any = d3.zoomIdentity
        .translate(newTranslateX, newTranslateY)
        .scale(transform.k * scaleDelta);

...
```